# Cookiecutter Django, Initial docker-compose build fails with docker error

Tags: django, docker, cookiecutter-django

I have created a fresh cookiecutter-django project on a windows machine.

The initial "docker-compose -f local.yml build" fails with "failed to solve: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y   build-essential   libpq-dev]: exit code: 100"

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I also had the same problem, to solve it I changed the `Dockerfile ` from `python:3.11.3-slim-bullseye ` to `python:3.10.10-slim-bullseye` after that everything was fine.